# How can you identify the date a GCP org policy was set at the organisation level?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I expect to find this information in logs.

However, the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/understanding-audit-logs) states;

> Note: Viewing folder and organization logs is not currently available through the Logs Viewer. To read log entries associated with the specified folder or organization, rather than the default project, use the Stackdriver Logging API method entries.list or see Reading log entries, to use the gcloud command-line tool.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the logs as I am not sure what filter to use to search for constraints as organization policies are defined as constraints.

For example, I would like to identify when the org policy "Require OS Login" was configured.

This is the command that I'm trying:

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type = organization AND textPayload:constraints/compute.requireOsLogin" --organization <org ID>
```

I expect the filter for constraints/compute.requireOsLogin is incorrect - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can execute a log filter using:

```
organizations/[ORGANIZATION_ID]/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Factivity
organizations/[ORGANIZATION_ID]/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access
organizations/[ORGANIZATION_ID]/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fsystem_event
```

as the log name.  This is where audit log data is written at the organization level.  This is going to return ALL the log data but if you then dump some of it and have a look, you are likely to see the pattern you are looking for.

Comment: thanks for this - i had tried these log filters but for some reason they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using the command below:

```
gcloud logging read "protoPayload.methodName=SetOrgPolicy AND protoPayload.serviceName=cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com AND protoPayload.request.constraint=constraints/compute.requireOsLogin" --organization=ORG-ID
```

You can also use Logging for one project under the organization with the filter below

```
protoPayload.methodName="SetOrgPolicy"

protoPayload.serviceName="cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com"

protoPayload.request.constraint="constraints/compute.requireOsLogin"
```

*Logging logs only last for 6 months